# Role Of Request.SetAttribute JSP

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

this is my jsp page :

```
          <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <title>Test EL</title>
     </head>
    <body>
    <p>

    <% 
    /* Creation */
    String[] animals = {"dog", "cat", "mouse", "horse"};
    request.setAttribute("animals" , animals);
    %>

    ${ animals[2] }<br />

</p>
</body>
```

What I don't understand is this : what is the utility of the instruction : "request.setAttribut", I already have the table declared and I don't see why when I remove that instruction I cant get the animals[2] value.. what am I missing here please?!

Comment: Please elaborate on "*cant get the animals[2] value*". What exactly happens?

Comment: I get an empty screen in my browser

Comment: I just ran your code. I don't see any error. Instead it is printing 'mouse', which is actual output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`${}` this a JSP EL expression. EL can only refer to *scoped* variables and not *local* variables. *Scoped* variables are references to objects added as an *attribute* to any one of the four scopes available which are `pageContext`, `request`, `session` and `application`.

In your example, `String[] animals` is a *local* variable and hence cannot be accessed through `${}` on its own. To make the `animals` array available for use with JSP EL, it needs to be put in any one of the available scopes first.

So, in your example, the following is placing the array in the `request` scope.

```
// restricted to current request cycle
request.setAttribute("animals" , animals);
```

You could also use any one of the following as per your applications requirements.

```
// restricted to this JSP page
pageContext.setAttribute("animals" , animals);

// restrcited to this user's session
session.setAttribute("animals" , animals);

// available throughout the application
application.setAttribute("animals" , animals);
```

The `${animals[i]}` automatically resolves the object from any one of the above scopes in the following order: first it looks in `pageContext`, then `request`, then `session`, and finally `application`.

To override the above lookup order, the *scope* can also be specified explicitly as

```
${pageScope.animals[i]}
${requestScope.animals[i]}
${sessionScope.animals[i]}
${applicationScope.animals[i]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to Ravi, If you still want to access the array without setting in one of those attributes, use jsp expression tag to display:

```
 Eg: <%=animals[2]%> <br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

As it's mentioned in the [**ServletRequest documentation**](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#setAttribute(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)) the `setAttribute()` method is used to store an attribute in the request so you can access it later.

And the `${variable}` is a jsp EL used to easily access these stored data in your web application, take a look at [**JSP - Expression Language (EL)**](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_expression_language.htm) for further information about it.

If you are in the same page where you declared your variable, you can avoid the use of setAttribute() and EL and print the variable result using `out.print()`  like this:

```
<%  out.println(animals[2]);%>
```